# Linking against a static library

Tags: c, makefile

gcc Version: 4:4.4.4-1ubuntu2
    GNU Make 3.81

I have the following library called `net_api.a` and some header files i.e.

```
network_set.h
```

I have include the header file in my source code in my main.c file

```
#include <network_set.h>
```

I have the following static library and header in the following directory

```
./tools/net/lib/net_api.a
./tools/net/inc/network_set.h
```

In my Makefile I have tried to link using the following, code snippet:

```
INC_PATH = -I tools/net/inc
LIB_PATH = -L tools/net/lib

LIBS = -lnet_api

$(TARGET): $(OBJECT_FILES)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $(INC_PATH) $(LIB_PATH) $(LIBS) $(OBJECT_FILES) -o $(TARGET)

main.o: main.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INC_PATH) $(LIB_PATH) -c main.c
```

However, when I compile I get the following errors:

```
network_set.h error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘network_String’
```

What is going wrong here?

Comment: Can you share the declaration of 'network_Sting' in network_set.h?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Compiling

The first problem you have to deal with is why the code is not compiling.  There is a problem in your `network_set.h` header; it is not self-contained in some way, so you have to include something else before including it, or you have to explicitly configure it in some way.  You should aim to have your headers both self-contained and idempotent.

- **self-contained** can be included without any other headers preceding it
- **idempotent** can be included multiple times without causing chaos

Self-containment is achieved by ensuring it can be the first header included in a source file and then compiles cleanly. It means that if it uses a feature (for example, `size_t`) then it includes a header that defines the feature (for example, `<stddef.h>`).

Idempotence is achieved by including a header guard:

```
#ifndef HEADER_H_INCLUDED
#define HEADER_H_INCLUDED
...main body of header...
#endif /* HEADER_H_INCLUDED */
```

I use the following script, called `chkhdr`, to ensure that headers are self-contained and idempotent.

```
#!/bin/ksh
#
# @(#)$Id: chkhdr.sh,v 1.2 2010/04/24 16:52:59 jleffler Exp $
#
# Check whether a header can be compiled standalone

tmp=chkhdr-$$
trap 'rm -f $tmp.?; exit 1' 0 1 2 3 13 15

cat >$tmp.c <<EOF
#include HEADER /* Check self-containment */
#include HEADER /* Check idempotency */
int main(void){return 0;}
EOF

options=
for file in "$@"
do
    case "$file" in
    (-*)    options="$options $file";;
    (*)     echo "$file:"
            gcc $options -DHEADER="\"$file\"" -c $tmp.c
            ;;
    esac
done

rm -f $tmp.?
trap 0
```

For example:

```
chkhdr -Itools/net/inc tools/net/inc/network_set.h
```

#### Linking

In due course, after you've fixed the compilation problems, you will run into linking problems.  The option `-lnet_api` looks for a library named `libnet_api.so` or `libnet_api.a`.

To link with `net_api.a`, you will have to pass the pathname to the file to the link command:

```
LIB_DIR     = ./tools/net/lib
LIB_NET_API = net_api.a
LIB_PATH    = -L ${LIB_DIR}

    ${CC} ... ${LIB_DIR}/${LIB_NET_API} ...
```

Obviously, you could define a macro for the path to the whole library.  Note how I redefined LIB_PATH in terms of the macro LIB_DIR.

Answer (score 2):

The header `network_set.h` has extra dependencies that must be included first, one of which is the definition of `network_String`.  Check the library documentation or consult the author for more details.

Comment: There is no other dependencies. I have also a windows 32 version of the static library. i.e. net_api.lib. It links ok with visual studio 2008 running windows xp. I am not too familiar with linking statics using a Makefile.

Comment: @ant2009: You aren't getting as far as the problems you are going to run into with the link phase; you are not successfully compiling main.c into main.o yet.

Answer (score 1):

You don't show your LDFLAGS; I assume they are defined but you just didn't post them. They must include "-static" if you're building against a static library.

If you don't know what they are, look at the compiler output at the start where it begins with "gcc" and see if "-static" shows up there.