# Problems in linking a subroutine to main file

Tags: c, linker

I am having difficulties while trying to link a file to my main code in order to interpolate a polynomial I have written minimal code and I have all the files used in the interpolation under the same directory. The files are from the book Numerical Recipes. I have minimal experience in linking external libraries and using subroutines in C. I would be glad if you can provide some assistance. The code and the associated files are as follows:
nrutil.c ; nrutil.h; POLINT.C

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <POLINT.C>
int main()
{
    int i;
    long double x[11], erf[11];
    for(i = 0; i <11; i++)
    {
        x[i] = i / 10.0;
        erf[i] = erfl(x[i]);
        printf("x is %Lf \n", x[i]);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What did you try to link it?

Comment: You are including a ".c" file?  Is there an associated header and compiled library?

Comment: You should find this link useful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15622409/how-to-link-multiple-implementation-files-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

Do not include POLINT.C

If you really have to compile everything all at once:

```
gcc POLINT.C nrutil.c -o nrutil -lm
```

Comment: Thanks I think that sort of worked out actually I copied and pasted part of the code to my main file and put an header as nrutil.h inside it and compiled it along with nrutil.c