# I copied this code from an example and it has an error, where is it coming from?

Tags: c++

```
//main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "Test.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    Test t;
    return 0;
}


//Test.h
#ifndef TEST_TEST_H
#define TEST_TEST_H


class Test {
public:
    Test();
};


#endif //TEST_TEST_H


//Test.cpp
#include "Test.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

Test::Test() {
    cout << "It worked";
}
```

I just started using C++ and I cannot figure out why this is not compiling. I am using the mingw compiler and CLion if that makes a difference with the error, I don't see why it would but I am being told that I need more detail...

Error message

```
C:\Users\Jason\AppData\Local\Temp\ccQ7aCrg.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x15): undefined reference to `Test::Test()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Is `Test.cpp` being compiled? The error implies that it can't find `Test::Test` when linking.

Comment: If the link in the 1st comment doesn't resolve your issue please include the compile(link) command that triggers the error.

Comment: It is compiling all right, it's not linking. It appears that you're only linking code from `main.cpp` and not `Test.cpp`. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15622496/1329652). To compile and link multiple files, do: `g++ -o program.exe main.cpp Test.cpp`. This will compile both `.cpp` files and link the results into `program.exe`.

Comment: This question is not the duplicate everyone thinks of. It is a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15622409/1329652) instead.

Comment: @NathanOliver Either we have the same misconceptions how that dupe should be helpful for newbs, or are finally right off many times along. Keep on flagging my friend.

Comment: @KubaOber The marked dupe covers that, believe it or not, it's really an awesome Q&A covering almost all of the situations that could cause that kind of linker error.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yeah, but the asker will not know which part of the wall of text in the supposed dupe is the answer that will help them. This looks like a rather straightforward newb mistake that my proposed dupe covers exactly.

Comment: @KubaOber At least mismatch of tags would deny to select your proposal as duplicate. All of the answers show compiling c code, rather than c++ code. Anyway I don't bother with the additional information given from your link, hopefully the OP is  intelligent enough to extrapolate.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thankfully gcc is cleverer than that :)

Comment: @KubaOber your explanation worked so thank you