# Tracing static inline function

Tags: c, static, macros, inline

I'm trying to add some debugging facility to my application and now stuck with using `static inline` function. As I learnt from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53939923/8990329) it was possible to put `static inline` function definition into a header file so function is not instantiated twice in case the file is included multiple times.

So I was curious and tried to define the similar `static inline` function for tracing invokation and put it into a header file:

```
#ifndef TRACE_H
#define TRACE_H

static inline void trace(){
    printf("Current line %d, func %s, file %s\n", __LINE__, __func__, __FILE__);
}

#endif //TRACE_H
```

I tried this because `static inline` is much less error-prone then macro. The problem is that the simple

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    trace(); 
}
```

prints `Current line 8, func trace, file /home/somename/include/trace.h` which is obviously useless.

So for tracing purpose is there any other way unless to define the macro

```
#define trace() \
    printf("Current line %d, func %s, file %s\n", __LINE__, __func__, __FILE__); \
```

Comment: \_\_func__ is the name of the current function whether it is inlined or not. You cannot encapsulate tracing functionality this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried this because static inline is much less error-prone then
>   macro.

Macros are dangerous when used with parameters that could be evaluated twice:

```
#define min(a, b) ((a) < (b)) ? (a) : (b)
```

But this is not the case.

The only workaround I can see is:

```
#define SOURCE __LINE__, __func__, __FILE__

static inline void trace(int line, const char *func, const char *file)
{
    printf("Current line %d, func %s, file %s\n", line, func, file);
}

int main(void)
{
    trace(SOURCE);
    ...
```

But still using the preprocessor.