# Generated header file does not include user-defined files

Tags: c, flex-lexer

Currently trying to create a lexer with Flex. When running the command `flex pl0_lexer.l`, the include statements in my pl0_lexer.h do not match my pl0_lexer.c.

**pl0_lexer.l Snippet**

```
%option header-file = "pl0_lexer.h"
%option outfile = "pl0_lexer.c"
%option yylineno
%option bison-bridge

%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include "ast.h"
#include "parser_types.h"
#include "utilities.h"
#include "lexer.h"

 /* Tokens generated by Bison */
#include "pl0.tab.h"
%}
```

[My problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77297450/generated-header-file-does-not-include-user-defined-files#comment136270781_77297450) is that all of the user-defined headers like `"ast.h"` appear in the `.c` code, but `pl0_lexer.h` only includes standard C headers.

Comment: Whaddya mean?  What gets produced that isn't as you expect?  Are you sure you looked far enough through the generated C code?

Comment: All of the user defined headers like "ast.h" appear in the .c code, but the pl0_lexer.h only includes the standard C libraries.

Comment: That's because the contents of `pl0_lexer.h` don't need any other headers to compile.  The header is minimal — your code (outside the lexer) has to include the headers necessary.  You can't rely on `pl0_lexer.h` to include those headers.

Comment: l added a `%%` line and a rule `. ECHO`, making the lexer minimally complete, though I suppose you could replace `ECHO` with `;` to be even smaller. See how to create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)
 — the same idea by a different name).   In this question, the issue is unrelated to what the lexer recognizes, so a minimal set of rules is appropriate.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I noted in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77297450/generated-header-file-does-not-include-user-defined-files#comment136270803_77297450):

> That's because the contents of `pl0_lexer.h` don't need any other headers to compile. The header is minimal — your code (outside the lexer) has to include the headers necessary. You can't rely on `pl0_lexer.h` to include those headers.

The generated header provides the definitions necessary to be able to use the lexer — primarily an appropriate declaration for `yylex()`, but also for the supporting functions.  It doesn't need to know anything about the information in the user-defined headers — those do not form a part of the interface to the lexical analyzer.

See also [Should I use `#include` in headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1804486/15168) for a discussion of self-contained, idempotent, minimal headers, and also [How to link multiple implementation files in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15622409/15168).

(As an aside, the generated header doesn't meet my definition of 'minimal'.  For example, it ensures that type names like `flex_int8_t` and `flex_uint64_t` are defined, but (with Flex 2.6.4) the structure defined in the header does not use these types, nor does anything else.  All that code is not directly needed in the header.  I'm not sure where it is documented that consumers of the lexical analyzer must (or should) use those types.)