# Why does this project compile without any include guards?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor, header-files, include-guards

I know that the use of include guards in header files is to prevent something from being defined twice. Using this code sample though, was completely fine:

foo.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "bar.h"

int main() {
    printf("%d", strlen("Test String"));
    somefunc("Some test string...");
    return 0;
}
```

bar.h

```
#ifndef BAR_H_INCLUDED
#define BAR_H_INCLUDED
void somefunc(char str[]);
#endif
```

bar.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "bar.h"

void somefunc(char str[]) {
    printf("Some string length function: %d", strlen(str));
}
```

The above snippets are compiled with `gcc -Wall foo.c bar.c -o foo` and there is no error. However, both `<stdio.h>` and `<string.h>` were included without an include guard. There is still no error when I strip bar.h down to the single statement `void somefunc(char str[]);`. Why is there no error?

Comment: Have you taken a look inside `stdio.h`?

Comment: I can't tell why you think there *should* be an error.

Comment: How do you know `stdio.h` and `string.h` don't **contain** guard macros? Did you check the files on your computer? The problem would arise e.g. when you have another header that includes your `bar.h` and in some other file, you include `bar.h` **and** this other header.

Comment: For the second part of the question: a function followed by a `;` instead of a body `{   }` is a forward declaration of the function. As long as the real function declaration doesn't contradict the forward declaration, there is no error.

Answer (score 7):

Firstly, the primary purpose of include guards is to prevent something from being declared twice *in the same translation unit*. The "in the same translation unit" part is the key here. Your experiment with two different translation units has nothing to do with the purpose of include guards. It does not demonstrate anything. It is not even remotely related.

In order to take advantage of include guards you have to include (explicitly or implicitly) the same header file twice into one implementation file.

Secondly, just because some header file has no include guards and just because you included that header file twice into the same translation unit does not mean that it will necessarily trigger errors. In order to lead to errors the header must contain declarations of specific "non-repeatable" kind. No every header contains such offending declarations. Not every declaration is offending in this sense.

Your `bar.h` (as posted) is actually harmless. Formally, you don't need include guards in your `bar.h`. It has a single function declaration, which can be repeated many times in one translation units. So, including this header multiple times will not lead to errors.

But add something like that to your `bar.h`

```
struct SomeStruct
{
  int i;
};
```

and then just include it twice in the same implementation file, and you will end up with an error. This error is what include guards are intended to prevent. The language prohibits repeating full declarations of the same struct type in the same translation unit.

Include guards are typically placed in header files unconditionally. They are, I'm quite sure, present inside `<stdio.h>` and `<string.h>` as well. It is unclear why you claim that these headers "were included without an include guard". Did you check inside these files? In any case, again, your experiment with two different translation units does not demonstrate anything relevant anyway.

Comment: @Antti Haapala: It would be more like that in C++. But in C the terminology is different. For example, C does not refer to a "full" declaration of struct type (i.e. with the `{...}`) as a *definition*. And a full declaration of struct type is a good example of a declaration that triggers this error.

Comment: Though, [C11 6.7.2.3p1]: *A specific type shall have its content **defined** at most once*, so the full declaration of a `struct` *defines* its content and it is this act of *definition* that must not be repeated.

Comment: @Antti Haapala: Well, "define" is a rather generic word, which would be hard to avoid using colloquially in formal text. It does not mean that every time the word "define" is used it is intended to refer to the standard concept of *definition*. In any case, I've been on the both sides of that debate... It appears that the formal terminology of the document intends to have *macro definitons*, *type definitions* (`typedef`) and *external definitions* (functions and variables) only. There seems to be no intent to introduce `struct { ... }` declarations as *definitions*.

Comment: I think it is quite good explained from you. But I am still wondering, what does it mean, "include it twice"? does it mean "include 'bar.h' in 'bar.cpp' twice"? That would be soo dumb, I guess nobody would even do that. So what is the point of the "include guards"?

Answer (score 4):

Duplicate declarations aren't a problem; duplicate (type) definitions are.  If the `bar.h` header contained, for example:

```
enum FooBar { FOO, BAR, BAZ, QUX };
```

then including that twice in a single TU (translation unit — source file plus included headers) would give an error in general.

Also, the multiple inclusion scenario isn't what you show.  What might cause the trouble is the following, assuming that there are no header guards in the header files:

- `bar.h`

  ```
  enum FooBar { FOO, BAR, BAZ, QUX };
  void somefunc(char str[]);
  ```
- `quack.h`

  ```
  #include "bar.h"
  extern enum FooBar foobar_translate(const char *str);
  ```
- `main.c`

  ```
  #include "bar.h"
  #include "quack.h"

  …
  ```

Note that GCC has an option `-Wredundant-decls` to identify redundant declarations — where the same declaration is present several times (normally from multiple files, but also if the same declaration is present twice in a single file).

Prior to C11, you could not repeat a `typedef` (at file scope; you always could hide an outer `typedef` in a block scope).  C11 relaxes that constraint:

> #### §6.7 Declarations
>
> ¶3 If an identifier has no linkage, there shall be no more than one declaration of the identifier
>   (in a declarator or type specifier) with the same scope and in the same name space, except
>   that:
>
> - a typedef name may be redefined to denote the same type as it currently does,
>     provided that type is not a variably modified type;
> - tags may be redeclared as specified in 6.7.2.3.

However, you still can't define a structure type twice in a single scope of a TU, so notations such as:

```
typedef struct StructTag { … } StructTag;
```

must be protected with header guards.  You don't have this problem if you use opaque (incomplete) types:

```
typedef struct StructTag StructTag;
```

As to why you can include standard headers, that's because the standard requires that you can:

> #### §7.1.2 Standard headers
>
> ¶4 Standard headers may be included in any order; each may be included more than once in
>   a given scope, with no effect different from being included only once, except that the
>   effect of including `<assert.h>` depends on the definition of `NDEBUG` (see 7.2). If
>   used, a header shall be included outside of any external declaration or definition, and it
>   shall first be included before the first reference to any of the functions or objects it
>   declares, or to any of the types or macros it defines. However, if an identifier is declared
>   or defined in more than one header, the second and subsequent associated headers may be
>   included after the initial reference to the identifier. The program shall not have any
>   macros with names lexically identical to keywords currently defined prior to the inclusion
>   of the header or when any macro defined in the header is expanded.

Using header guards allows you to make your headers meet the same standard that the standard headers meet.

See also other diatribes (answers) on the general subject, including:

- [Should I use `#include` in headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1804486)
- [How do I use `extern` to share variables between source files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204) — the information is a fair way down my humungous answer in a section on header guards.
- [Repeated typedefs — invalid in C but valid in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8594954)
- [How to link multiple implementation files in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15622409)
- [Linking against a static library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507896) — contains a script `chkhdr` which I use to check headers for idempotency and self-containment.

Answer (score 2):

The reason there is no error in your code is that your header file is declaring but not defining `somefunc()`.  Multiple declarations of something are fine, as long as they are not definitions - the compiler can accept seeing something declared more than once (as long as the declarations are compatible, of course).

Generally speaking, include guards are needed to avoid circular dependencies between header files, such as

- Header A and header B mutually include each other in some situations.  An include guard is needed in at least one of the headers to prevent infinite looping in the preprocessor.
- Header A includes header B because it depends on a definition (e.g. of an inline function, a `typedef`) within it, but other header files OR compilation units may include header A, header B, or both in different circumstances.   Include guards are needed to prevent multiple definitions in compilation units that include both those headers.  At a minimum, the header file containing the definitions needs to have an include guard.

Since header files can include each other in any order, problems like those addressed above can become quite complicated.

Preventing some types of multiple definition is a side-effect of the above, but is not the primary purpose of include guards.

Not withstanding all the above, the rule of thumb I work by with header files is "use include guards in all header files unless I have a particular reason not to".   By doing that, all the potential problems associated with not providing include guards are avoided.   The circumstances in which it is necessary to avoid an include guard (such as the header declaring or defining different things, dependent on a macro being defined/undefined in the compilation unit) are relatively rare in practice.   And, if you are using such techniques which require such things, you should already know that you should not be using include guards in the affected headers.

Answer (score 0):

Why? Because:

```
int char_to_int(char* value, int *res);
int char_to_int(char* value, int *res);
int char_to_int(char* value, int *res);
int char_to_int(char* value, int *res);
int char_to_int(char* value, int *res);
int char_to_int(char* value, int *res);
int char_to_int(char* value, int *res);
int char_to_int(char* value, int *res);
int char_to_int(char* value, int *res);
int char_to_int(char* value, int *res);
int char_to_int(char* value, int *res);
int char_to_int(char* value, int *res);
int char_to_int(char* value, int *res);
int char_to_int(char* value, int *res);
int char_to_int(char* value, int *res);

int char_to_int(char* value, int *res)
{
    // do something
}
```

Function prototypes do not error it they are the same and the function